# Scrape Instagram bio using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, instagram

I am a beginner with web-scraping and I am trying to make a program which scrapes the bio of someone their Instagram biography.

I read both Selenium and BS are famous libraries for web scraping. I went for Beautiful Soup simply because I had zero experience with Selenium. At first, I just wanted to scrape the bio of a list of Instagram names (`username = ['python', 'apple', 'windows']`). I got this to work, then I decided to only print out the biographies of the usernames which contain one or more words from a list containing string (`keyword = ['Amsterdam', 'Delft', 'Utrecht']`).

First, I tested this program with a list of 10 usernames. I worked like a charm and did exactly what I wanted; printed out all biographies of the Instagram users containing one or more words from `username`.

The program first scrapes the HTML-content from the page, and then looks for all the text between two strings. These strings are always before and after the biography. This probably is not the most efficient way to do it, but it worked for me. Feedback on this would be appreciated.

After a few tests on lists containing 5, 10 or 20 usernames I decided to throw 600 accounts in a comma separated list and see what the results would be (at this moment I did not know Instagram allows 200 request/hour on their website per IP address). After the code execution was done I saw some things did not went well, the output of the code was not what I expected. Some usernames went through, and sometimes it suddenly printed the entire soup instead of the bio.

I think that Instagram blacklisted (?) my IP and now requires me to log in on their web-page before I can see people their profile pages.

My main question comes now; how can I be logged in on my Instagram page so BS can scrape the HTML content I am looking for instead of the HTML of the Instagram login page.

**My code**

```
import bs4, requests

username = ['python', 'apple', 'windows']
keyword = ['Amsterdam', 'Delft', 'Utrecht']

for i in username:
#    if len(username) > 200:
# Instagram only allows 200 requests/hour on their website. 
#        break
    res = requests.get('http://www.instagram.com/' + i)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    start = '"description":"'
    end = '","mainEntityofPage"'
    s = str(soup)
    bio = s[s.find(start)+len(start):s.rfind(end)]
    if any(keyword in bio for keyword in keyword):
        print(i)
        print(bio)
```

**This is what my program scrapes now after Instagram requires me to login in order to see people their profile pages.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js not-logged-in client-root" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<title>
Login • Instagram
</title>
<meta content="noimageindex, noarchive" name="robots"/>
<meta content="default" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style"/>
<meta content="yes" name="mobile-web-app-capable"/>
<meta content="#ffffff" name="theme-color"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover" id="viewport" name="viewport"/>
<link href="/data/manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
<link as="style" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/ConsumerUICommons.css/0d73027e4285.css" rel="preload" type="text/css">
<link as="style" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/ConsumerAsyncCommons.css/638f1bd337c8.css" rel="preload" type="text/css"/>
<link as="style" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/Consumer.css/3e0c88f3bf5f.css" rel="preload" type="text/css"/>
<link as="style" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/FBSignupPage.css/5e365c4760d1.css" rel="preload" type="text/css"/>
<link as="style" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/LoginAndSignupPage.css/6a800c588f0a.css" rel="preload" type="text/css"/>
<link as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/Vendor.js/5a56d51ae30f.js" rel="preload" type="text/javascript"/>
<link as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/en_US.js/d9caef98221d.js" rel="preload" type="text/javascript"/>
<link as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/ConsumerLibCommons.js/5f7a507341f1.js" rel="preload" type="text/javascript"/>
<link as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/ConsumerUICommons.js/8ecd467c3b01.js" rel="preload" type="text/javascript"/>
<link as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/ConsumerAsyncCommons.js/fb427bc425ce.js" rel="preload" type="text/javascript"/>
<link as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/Consumer.js/7b5582822f50.js" rel="preload" type="text/javascript"/>
<link as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/FBSignupPage.js/41480d7ada82.js" rel="preload" type="text/javascript"/>
<link as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/LoginAndSignupPage.js/e69506f83a66.js" rel="preload" type="text/javascript"/>
<link as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/FeedPageContainer.js/b3f110c97771.js" rel="prefetch" type="text/javascript"/>
<link as="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/FeedPageContainer.css/aeb2597a11c0.css" rel="prefetch" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
  var docElement = document.documentElement;
  var classRE = new RegExp('(^|\\s)no-js(\\s|$)');
  var className = docElement.className;
  docElement.className = className.replace(classRE, '$1js$2');
})();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  if ('PerformanceObserver' in window && 'PerformancePaintTiming' in window) {
    window.__bufferedPerformance = [];
    var ob = new PerformanceObserver(function(e) {
      window.__bufferedPerformance.push.apply(window.__bufferedPerformance,e.getEntries());
    });
    ob.observe({entryTypes:['paint']});
  }

  window.__bufferedErrors = [];
  window.onerror = function(message, url, line, column, error) {
    window.__bufferedErrors.push({
      message: message,
      url: url,
      line: line,
      column: column,
      error: error
    });
    return false;
  };
  window.__initialData = {
    pending: true,
    waiting: []
  };
  function asyncFetchSharedData(extra) {
    var sharedDataReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    sharedDataReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (sharedDataReq.readyState === 4) {
            if(sharedDataReq.status === 200){
              var sharedData = JSON.parse(sharedDataReq.responseText);
              window.__initialDataLoaded(sharedData, extra);
            }
          }
        }
    sharedDataReq.open('GET', '/data/shared_data/', true);
    sharedDataReq.send(null);
  }
  function notifyLoaded(item, data) {
    item.pending = false;
    item.data = data;
    for (var i = 0;i < item.waiting.length; ++i) {
      item.waiting[i].resolve(item.data);
    }
    item.waiting = [];
  }
  function notifyError(item, msg) {
    item.pending = false;
    item.error = new Error(msg);
    for (var i = 0;i < item.waiting.length; ++i) {
      item.waiting[i].reject(item.error);
    }
    item.waiting = [];
  }
  window.__initialDataLoaded = function(initialData, extraData) {
    if (extraData) {
      for (var key in extraData) {
        initialData[key] = extraData[key];
      }
    }
    notifyLoaded(window.__initialData, initialData);
  };
  window.__initialDataError = function(msg) {
    notifyError(window.__initialData, msg);
  };
  window.__additionalData = {};
  window.__pendingAdditionalData = function(paths) {
    for (var i = 0;i < paths.length; ++i) {
      window.__additionalData[paths[i]] = {
        pending: true,
        waiting: []
      };
    }
  };
  window.__additionalDataLoaded = function(path, data) {
    if (path in window.__additionalData) {
      notifyLoaded(window.__additionalData[path], data);
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected additional data loaded "' + path + '"');
    }
  };
  window.__additionalDataError = function(path, msg) {
    if (path in window.__additionalData) {
      notifyError(window.__additionalData[path], msg);
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected additional data encountered an error "' + path + '": ' + msg);
    }
  };

})();
</script><script type="text/javascript">

/*
 Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
*/

(function(){function g(a,c){b||(b=a,f=c,h.forEach(function(a){removeEventListener(a,l,e)}),m())}function m(){b&&f&&0<d.length&&(d.forEach(function(a){a(b,f)}),d=[])}function n(a,c){function k(){g(a,c);d()}function b(){d()}function d(){removeEventListener("pointerup",k,e);removeEventListener("pointercancel",b,e)}addEventListener("pointerup",k,e);addEventListener("pointercancel",b,e)}function l(a){if(a.cancelable){var c=performance.now(),b=a.timeStamp;b>c&&(c=+new Date);c-=b;"pointerdown"==a.type?n(c,
a):g(c,a)}}var e={passive:!0,capture:!0},h=["click","mousedown","keydown","touchstart","pointerdown"],b,f,d=[];h.forEach(function(a){addEventListener(a,l,e)});window.perfMetrics=window.perfMetrics||{};window.perfMetrics.onFirstInputDelay=function(a){d.push(a);m()}})();
</script>
<link href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-76x76-precomposed.png/666282be8229.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76"/>
<link href="/static/images/ico/favicon.ico/36b3ee2d91ed.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
<meta content="Welcome back to Instagram. Sign in to check out what your friends, family &amp; interests have been capturing &amp; sharing around the world." name="description">
</link></link></link></link></link></link></link></link></meta></link></head>
<body class="" style="
    background: white;
">
<div id="react-root">
</div>nativePerformanceNow():Date.now(),__DEV__=false,process=this.process||{};process.env=process.env||{};process.env.NODE_ENV=process.env.NODE_ENV||"production";!(function(r){"use strict";function e(){return c=Object.create(null)}function t(r){var e=r,t=c[e];return t&&t.isInitialized?t.publicModule.exports:o(e,t)}function n(r){var e=r;if(c[e]&&c[e].importedDefault!==f)return c[e].importedDefault;var n=t(e),i=n&&n.__esModule?n.default:n;return c[e].importedDefault=i}function i(r){var e=r;if(c[e]&&c[e].importedAll!==f)return c[e].importedAll;var n,i=t(e);if(i&&i.__esModule)n=i;else{if(n={},i)for(var o in i)p.call(i,o)&&(n[o]=i[o]);n.default=i}return c[e].importedAll=n}function o(e,t){if(!s&&r.ErrorUtils){s=!0;var n;try{n=u(e,t)}catch(e){r.ErrorUtils.reportFatalError(e)}return s=!1,n}return u(e,t)}function l(r){return{segmentId:r>>>v,localId:r&h}}function u(e,o){if(!o&&g.length>0){var u=l(e),f=u.segmentId,p=u.localId,s=g[f];null!=s&&(s(p),o=c[e])}var v=r.nativeRequire;if(!o&&v){var h=l(e),I=h.segmentId;v(h.localId,I),o=c[e]}if(!o)throw a(e);if(o.hasError)throw d(e,o.error);o.isInitialized=!0;var _=o,w=_.factory,y=_.dependencyMap;try{var M=o.publicModule;if(M.id=e,m.length>0)for(var b=0;b<m.length;++b)m[b].cb(e,M);return w(r,t,n,i,M,M.exports,y),o.factory=void 0,o.dependencyMap=void 0,M.exports}catch(r){throw o.hasError=!0,o.error=r,o.isInitialized=!1,o.publicModule.exports=void 0,r}}function a(r){var e='Requiring unknown module "'+r+'".';return Error(e)}function d(r,e){var t=r;return Error('Requiring module "'+t+'", which threw an exception: '+e)}r.__r=t,r.__d=function(r,e,t){null==c[e]&&(c[e]={dependencyMap:t,factory:r,hasError:!1,importedAll:f,importedDefault:f,isInitialized:!1,publicModule:{exports:{}}})},r.__c=e,r.__registerSegment=function(r,e){g[r]=e};var c=e(),f={},p={}.hasOwnProperty;t.importDefault=n,t.importAll=i;var s=!1,v=16,h=65535;t.unpackModuleId=l,t.packModuleId=function(r){return(r.segmentId<<v)+r.localId};var m=[];t.registerHook=function(r){var e={cb:r};return m.push(e),{release:function(){for(var r=0;r<m.length;++r)if(m[r]===e){m.splice(r,1);break}}}};var g=[]})('undefined'!=typeof global?global:'undefined'!=typeof window?window:this);
__s={"js":{"146":"/static/bundles/metro/EncryptionUtils.js/21a28b4798c8.js","147":"/static/bundles/metro/MobileStoriesLoginPage.js/7d6257c8ec15.js","148":"/static/bundles/metro/DesktopStoriesLoginPage.js/272aac4d9136.js","149":"/static/bundles/metro/AvenyFont.js/bf0ef5ae6bb7.js","150":"/static/bundles/metro/DirectSearchUserContainer.js/c2eba1411beb.js","151":"/static/bundles/metro/MobileStoriesPage.js/5cf6509be0b8.js","152":"/static/bundles/metro/DesktopStoriesPage.js/7b4f37c27d36.js","153":"/static/bundles/metro/ActivityFeedPage.js/5c47a202666b.js","154":"/static/bundles/metro/AdsSettingsPage.js/9b614999713d.js","155":"/static/bundles/metro/DonateCheckoutPage.js/8fb6e2a42039.js","156":"/static/bundles/metro/CameraPage.js/f6033f5723e3.js","157":"/static/bundles/metro/SettingsModules.js/d925c6f55849.js","158":"/static/bundles/metro/ContactHistoryPage.js/de07480f659e.js","159":"/static/bundles/metro/AccessToolPage.js/2b5e6df3f22f.js","160":"/static/bundles/metro/AccessToolViewAllPage.js/7ad4b4e961eb.js","161":"/static/bundles/metro/AccountPrivacyBugPage.js/eccedfece3dd.js","162":"/static/bundles/metro/FirstPartyPlaintextPasswordLandingPage.js/749e746ababd.js","163":"/static/bundles/metro/ThirdPartyPlaintextPasswordLandingPage.js/04452f220a41.js","164":"/static/bundles/metro/ShoppingBagLandingPage.js/158786aa9d35.js","165":"/static/bundles/metro/PlaintextPasswordBugPage.js/ecf56b41e737.js","166":"/static/bundles/metro/PrivateAccountMadePublicBugPage.js/781b717b4cd1.js","167":"/static/bundles/metro/PublicAccountNotMadePrivateBugPage.js/53441c285241.js","168":"/static/bundles/metro/BlockedAccountsBugPage.js/cebaea528300.js","169":"/static/bundles/metro/AndroidBetaPrivacyBugPage.js/f2e6cb1285fe.js","170":"/static/bundles/metro/DataControlsSupportPage.js/75f18c3f266e.js","171":"/static/bundles/metro/DataDownloadRequestPage.js/5aa3ac0ec2cb.js","172":"/static/bundles/metro/DataDownloadRequestConfirmPage.js/b2ad5a701aa4.js","173":"/static/bundles/metro/CheckpointUnderageAppealPage.js/0f25d27f8993.js","174":"/static/bundles/metro/AccountRecoveryLandingPage.js/8471e989b984.js","175":"/static/bundles/metro/ContactInvitesOptOutPage.js/61fd28c6a2f7.js","176":"/static/bundles/metro/ParentalConsentPage.js/d3fdcd7806cd.js","177":"/static/bundles/metro/ParentalConsentNotParentPage.js/f94652cad9da.js","178":"/static/bundles/metro/TermsAcceptPage.js/0cb8e1a69da1.js","179":"/static/bundles/metro/TermsUnblockPage.js/36460734b680.js","180":"/static/bundles/metro/NewTermsConfirmPage.js/6a059e0714fe.js","181":"/static/bundles/metro/ContactInvitesOptOutStatusPage.js/fc77a01cbaed.js","182":"/static/bundles/metro/CreationModules.js/fff5e2f52f7a.js","183":"/static/bundles/metro/StoryCreationPage.js/54a2af162773.js","184":"/static/bundles/metro/PostCommentInput.js/21b2a39b6d35.js","187":"/static/bundles/metro/PostModalEntrypoint.js/436bfe0aec90.js","188":"/static/bundles/metro/PostComments.js/b5a054b2aa94.js","189":"/static/bundles/metro/LikedByListContainer.js/e5f9ddaa4e0a.js","190":"/static/bundles/metro/CommentLikedByListContainer.js/d1449ad5139c.js","191":"/static/bundles/metro/shaka-player.ui.js/3f7b6e36c82f.js","192":"/static/bundles/metro/DynamicExploreMediaPage.js/026348269f30.js","193":"/static/bundles/metro/DiscoverMediaPageContainer.js/f58bae4b5136.js","194":"/static/bundles/metro/DiscoverPeoplePageContainer.js/939b31ea2c72.js","195":"/static/bundles/metro/EmailConfirmationPage.js/9cfc9ad540f0.js","196":"/static/bundles/metro/EmailReportBadPasswordResetPage.js/fa4bbd2dd77a.js","197":"/static/bundles/metro/FBSignupPage.js/41480d7ada82.js","198":"/static/bundles/metro/NewUserInterstitial.js/a6fd21f93914.js","199":"/static/bundles/metro/MultiStepSignupPage.js/e087dde7624e.js","200":"/static/bundles/metro/EmptyFeedPage.js/2bf8c553abda.js","201":"/static/bundles/metro/NewUserActivatorsUnit.js/57c2691d587c.js","202":"/static/bundles/metro/FeedEndSuggestedUserUnit.js/7755a00c63b3.js","203":"/static/bundles/metro/FeedSidebarContainer.js/ce6342991fc3.js","204":"/static/bundles/metro/SuggestedUserFeedUnitContainer.js/bfe6ef5a7fba.js","205":"/static/bundles/metro/InFeedStoryTray.js/83e29d3f5bec.js","206":"/static/bundles/metro/FeedPageContainer.js/b3f110c97771.js","207":"/static/bundles/metro/FollowListModal.js/bea7716ac959.js","208":"/static/bundles/metro/FollowListPage.js/27fd24f213d3.js","209":"/static/bundles/metro/SimilarAccountsPage.js/313ef0f77ef6.js","210":"/static/bundles/metro/LiveBroadcastPage.js/2296ef8e617b.js","211":"/static/bundles/metro/FalseInformationLandingPage.js/757fc05b7292.js","212":"/static/bundles/metro/LandingPage.js/0ff9b7f17621.js","213":"/static/bundles/metro/LocationsDirectoryCountryPage.js/6f4847f40a53.js","214":"/static/bundles/metro/LocationsDirectoryCityPage.js/37fa779217db.js","215":"/static/bundles/metro/LocationPageContainer.js/b8321253bc7f.js","216":"/static/bundles/metro/LocationsDirectoryLandingPage.js/9cc0691f6310.js","217":"/static/bundles/metro/LoginAndSignupPage.js/e69506f83a66.js","218":"/static/bundles/metro/FXCalLinkingAuthForm.js/82e42c50090e.js","219":"/static/bundles/metro/UpdateIGAppForHelpPage.js/546758ec0ad3.js","220":"/static/bundles/metro/ResetPasswordPageContainer.js/85023203d515.js","221":"/static/bundles/metro/MobileAllCommentsPage.js/25a39a1281dd.js","222":"/static/bundles/metro/MediaChainingPageContainer.js/e11b71a2fd61.js","223":"/static/bundles/metro/PostPageContainer.js/7f2433ef564e.js","224":"/static/bundles/metro/ProfilesDirectoryLandingPage.js/d659333a33ed.js","225":"/static/bundles/metro/HashtagsDirectoryLandingPage.js/fd350042361c.js","226":"/static/bundles/metro/SuggestedDirectoryLandingPage.js/e36154ea0ac1.js","227":"/static/bundles/metro/TagPageContainer.js/3a4d43da340c.js","228":"/static/bundles/metro/PhoneConfirmPage.js/4e12cdcc5a2c.js","229":"/static/bundles/metro/SimilarAccountsModal.js/fb7c6de39211.js","230":"/static/bundles/metro/ProfilePageContainer.js/ca32d4a69797.js","231":"/static/bundles/metro/HttpErrorPage.js/63f8a0711203.js","232":"/static/bundles/metro/IGTVVideoDraftsPageContainer.js/40d8d1cf10ca.js","233":"/static/bundles/metro/IGTVVideoUploadPageContainer.js/26bb95400395.js","234":"/static/bundles/metro/OAuthPermissionsPage.js/50bd38087dc3.js","235":"/static/bundles/metro/MobileDirectPage.js/f56c04d07c62.js","236":"/static/bundles/metro/DesktopDirectPage.js/68df22cedbcc.js","237":"/static/bundles/metro/GuidePage.js/d48cbbc77278.js","238":"/static/bundles/metro/OneTapUpsell.js/d937d7841de2.js","239":"/static/bundles/metro/NametagLandingPage.js/2ba20bdd48b6.js","240":"/static/bundles/metro/LocalDevTransactionToolSelectorPage.js/b21c685e9306.js","241":"/static/bundles/metro/FBEAppStoreErrorPage.js/61f766363fb1.js","242":"/static/bundles/metro/BloksShellPage.js/cd674ed760eb.js","243":"/static/bundles/metro/BusinessCategoryPageContainer.js/3417d67ba3a7.js","244":"/static/bundles/metro/ActivityFeedBox.js/63a716747d79.js","245":"/static/bundles/metro/DirectMQTT.js/fcd5d4f1173d.js","246":"/static/bundles/metro/DebugInfoNub.js/75af187fde21.js","248":"/static/bundles/metro/Consumer.js/7b5582822f50.js","249":"/static/bundles/metro/Challenge.js/fde38420bbd8.js","250":"/static/bundles/metro/NotificationLandingPage.js/e685d3db3d34.js","268":"/static/bundles/metro/EmbedAsyncLogger.js/7734c822ea88.js","270":"/static/bundles/metro/EmbedVideoWrapper.js/f3dc7f5a0721.js","271":"/static/bundles/metro/EmbedSidecarEntrypoint.js/8eaecdfd00af.js","272":"/static/bundles/metro/EmbedRich.js/36ebdcab0457.js"},"css":{"147":"/static/bundles/metro/MobileStoriesLoginPage.css/63c8b55730f8.css","148":"/static/bundles/metro/DesktopStoriesLoginPage.css/eddb32f57044.css","149":"/static/bundles/metro/AvenyFont.css/25fd69ff2266.css","150":"/static/bundles/metro/DirectSearchUserContainer.css/ee79587484d2.css","151":"/static/bundles/metro/MobileStoriesPage.css/c25ac24ea04c.css","152":"/static/bundles/metro/DesktopStoriesPage.css/8c70943b7240.css","153":"/static/bundles/metro/ActivityFeedPage.css/5dce34641195.css","154":"/static/bundles/metro/AdsSettingsPage.css/5293e36a780d.css","155":"/static/bundles/metro/DonateCheckoutPage.css/5293e36a780d.css","156":"/static/bundles/metro/CameraPage.css/6a60610e77f3.css","157":"/static/bundles/metro/SettingsModules.css/e1e09a4fbbb6.css","158":"/static/bundles/metro/ContactHistoryPage.css/6450a9697d3b.css","159":"/static/bundles/metro/AccessToolPage.css/34921b2f36dd.css","160":"/static/bundles/metro/AccessToolViewAllPage.css/ddca305d0cd5.css","161":"/static/bundles/metro/AccountPrivacyBugPage.css/b084aece73a3.css","164":"/static/bundles/metro/ShoppingBagLandingPage.css/9ea9da8878b6.css","169":"/static/bundles/metro/AndroidBetaPrivacyBugPage.css/158f7ff45015.css","170":"/static/bundles/metro/DataControlsSupportPage.css/2c93110330b6.css","171":"/static/bundles/metro/DataDownloadRequestPage.css/e1c17cd74c8c.css","172":"/static/bundles/metro/DataDownloadRequestConfirmPage.css/1e9cdea74d83.css","173":"/static/bundles/metro/CheckpointUnderageAppealPage.css/696e09a280c9.css","174":"/static/bundles/metro/AccountRecoveryLandingPage.css/ec80e8c27b35.css","175":"/static/bundles/metro/ContactInvitesOptOutPage.css/16fb0ada266f.css","176":"/static/bundles/metro/ParentalConsentPage.css/ae79aa7843e4.css","177":"/static/bundles/metro/ParentalConsentNotParentPage.css/6308e4086754.css","178":"/static/bundles/metro/TermsAcceptPage.css/f93160eb7986.css","179":"/static/bundles/metro/TermsUnblockPage.css/a3ac7fdd5ad3.css","180":"/static/bundles/metro/NewTermsConfirmPage.css/44b571a6a961.css","181":"/static/bundles/metro/ContactInvitesOptOutStatusPage.css/c71af4588c9c.css","182":"/static/bundles/metro/CreationModules.css/7679d64d0d74.css","183":"/static/bundles/metro/StoryCreationPage.css/a5c65c300576.css","184":"/static/bundles/metro/PostCommentInput.css/94eff2a7019d.css","187":"/static/bundles/metro/PostModalEntrypoint.css/22326130afec.css","188":"/static/bundles/metro/PostComments.css/2c4993169770.css","189":"/static/bundles/metro/LikedByListContainer.css/cfbb06eb7d39.css","190":"/static/bundles/metro/CommentLikedByListContainer.css/cfbb06eb7d39.css","192":"/static/bundles/metro/DynamicExploreMediaPage.css/1bb7a38564a8.css","193":"/static/bundles/metro/DiscoverMediaPageContainer.css/da8cde591698.css","194":"/static/bundles/metro/DiscoverPeoplePageContainer.css/9675385ad57c.css","195":"/static/bundles/metro/EmailConfirmationPage.css/d3ff48c961de.css","196":"/static/bundles/metro/EmailReportBadPasswordResetPage.css/e4462019534b.css","197":"/static/bundles/metro/FBSignupPage.css/5e365c4760d1.css","198":"/static/bundles/metro/NewUserInterstitial.css/985ba0d5ab88.css","199":"/static/bundles/metro/MultiStepSignupPage.css/a68014a02954.css","200":"/static/bundles/metro/EmptyFeedPage.css/aca00e00c692.css","202":"/static/bundles/metro/FeedEndSuggestedUserUnit.css/97ff07a6ffa3.css","203":"/static/bundles/metro/FeedSidebarContainer.css/a5a0913586eb.css","204":"/static/bundles/metro/SuggestedUserFeedUnitContainer.css/cbc64528fb4d.css","205":"/static/bundles/metro/InFeedStoryTray.css/2f6c17556f2d.css","206":"/static/bundles/metro/FeedPageContainer.css/aeb2597a11c0.css","207":"/static/bundles/metro/FollowListModal.css/d7b3e1b5a813.css","208":"/static/bundles/metro/FollowListPage.css/e86b8808fd5f.css","209":"/static/bundles/metro/SimilarAccountsPage.css/90677d6b5976.css","210":"/static/bundles/metro/LiveBroadcastPage.css/00214dc782ca.css","212":"/static/bundles/metro/LandingPage.css/987c457c15e6.css","213":"/static/bundles/metro/LocationsDirectoryCountryPage.css/4dacfdb3fce0.css","214":"/static/bundles/metro/LocationsDirectoryCityPage.css/4dacfdb3fce0.css","215":"/static/bundles/metro/LocationPageContainer.css/3a5198223b15.css","216":"/static/bundles/metro/LocationsDirectoryLandingPage.css/8d8beac67daf.css","217":"/static/bundles/metro/LoginAndSignupPage.css/6a800c588f0a.css","218":"/static/bundles/metro/FXCalLinkingAuthForm.css/5755af3a0372.css","219":"/static/bundles/metro/UpdateIGAppForHelpPage.css/6fb2336f846b.css","220":"/static/bundles/metro/ResetPasswordPageContainer.css/68d92b16f480.css","221":"/static/bundles/metro/MobileAllCommentsPage.css/0da816d28cac.css","222":"/static/bundles/metro/MediaChainingPageContainer.css/f3a3c93c915b.css","223":"/static/bundles/metro/PostPageContainer.css/cceaf334f417.css","224":"/static/bundles/metro/ProfilesDirectoryLandingPage.css/b406e80cc262.css","225":"/static/bundles/metro/HashtagsDirectoryLandingPage.css/b406e80cc262.css","226":"/static/bundles/metro/SuggestedDirectoryLandingPage.css/b406e80cc262.css","227":"/static/bundles/metro/TagPageContainer.css/47d968faa0fd.css","228":"/static/bundles/metro/PhoneConfirmPage.css/d899349b3a7b.css","230":"/static/bundles/metro/ProfilePageContainer.css/e50307deea72.css","231":"/static/bundles/metro/HttpErrorPage.css/97acfee23c4f.css","232":"/static/bundles/metro/IGTVVideoDraftsPageContainer.css/fb2011d7dca4.css","233":"/static/bundles/metro/IGTVVideoUploadPageContainer.css/8f1406ecfdde.css","234":"/static/bundles/metro/OAuthPermissionsPage.css/f127ac651626.css","235":"/static/bundles/metro/MobileDirectPage.css/43b3aa3ac302.css","236":"/static/bundles/metro/DesktopDirectPage.css/2d8749680809.css","237":"/static/bundles/metro/GuidePage.css/1a1a31a009ea.css","238":"/static/bundles/metro/OneTapUpsell.css/6749fb274e6d.css","239":"/static/bundles/metro/NametagLandingPage.css/a354587c3fd6.css","240":"/static/bundles/metro/LocalDevTransactionToolSelectorPage.css/3f8f9bb4c8a7.css","241":"/static/bundles/metro/FBEAppStoreErrorPage.css/37c4f5efdab6.css","242":"/static/bundles/metro/BloksShellPage.css/777f576eec93.css","243":"/static/bundles/metro/BusinessCategoryPageContainer.css/b077c4372cce.css","244":"/static/bundles/metro/ActivityFeedBox.css/e4504d071c5f.css","246":"/static/bundles/metro/DebugInfoNub.css/4bc325bd3e84.css","248":"/static/bundles/metro/Consumer.css/3e0c88f3bf5f.css","249":"/static/bundles/metro/Challenge.css/5d5008948b86.css","270":"/static/bundles/metro/EmbedVideoWrapper.css/1f3ba57046cb.css","271":"/static/bundles/metro/EmbedSidecarEntrypoint.css/bb920a294a50.css","272":"/static/bundles/metro/EmbedRich.css/425858679905.css"}}</script>type="text/javascript"></script>
<script async="" charset="utf-8" crossorigin="anonymous" src="/static/bundles/metro/Consumer.js/7b5582822f50.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script async="" charset="utf-8" crossorigin="anonymous" src="/static/bundles/metro/FBSignupPage.js/41480d7ada82.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script async="" charset="utf-8" crossorigin="anonymous" src="/static/bundles/metro/LoginAndSignupPage.js/e69506f83a66.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
  function normalizeError(err) {
    var errorInfo = err.error || {};
    var getConfigProp = function(propName, defaultValueIfNotTruthy) {
      var propValue = window._sharedData && window._sharedData[propName];
      return propValue ? propValue : defaultValueIfNotTruthy;
    };
    is_canary = getConfigProp('is_canary', false);
    is_c1 = getConfigProp('is_c1', is_canary);
    return {
      line: err.line || errorInfo.message || 0,
      column: err.column || 0,
      name: 'InitError',
      message: err.message || errorInfo.message || '',
      script: errorInfo.script || '',
      stack: errorInfo.stackTrace || errorInfo.stack || '',
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      ref: window.location.href,
      deployment_stage: getConfigProp('deployment_stage', ''),
      is_c1: is_c1,
      is_canary: is_canary,
      rollout_hash: getConfigProp('rollout_hash', ''),
      is_prerelease: window.__PRERELEASE__ || false,
      bundle_variant: getConfigProp('bundle_variant', null),
      request_url: err.url || window.location.href,
      response_status_code: errorInfo.statusCode ||0
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if (window.__bufferedErrors && window.__bufferedErrors.length) {
      if (window.caches && window.caches.keys && window.caches.delete) {
        window.caches.keys().then(function(keys) {
          keys.forEach(function(key) {
            window.caches.delete(key)
          })
        })
      }
      window.__bufferedErrors.map(function(error) {
        return normalizeError(error)
      }).forEach(function(normalizedError) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', '/client_error/', true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        request.send(JSON.stringify(normalizedError));
      })
    }
  })
}());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*I deleted some parts of the code because else I would exceed the character limit of Stackoverflow.*

As you can see, this code is the code of the login page and not someone their profile page.

I hope someone can help me out. If this post missed any crucial information please let me know.
Feedback is appreciated as well.